# Track outbound links using Universal analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've just added the following 'Universal' analytics code to th[e head][1] and can't find how to set a standard, universal outbound tracking event:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxx-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

This is what has been suggested:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {

      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Outbound', 'Click', this.href]);
      setTimeout('document.location = "' + this.href + '"', 100);
      return false;
}
```

Is this for universal outbound event tracking? Does it track all events and where should it be placed - in the head or before body closing tag?

Is this the correct syntax for tracking individual universal events?

```
onclick="trackOutboundLink('/WEBSITE/www.something.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://github.com/tomfuertes/jquery-universal-analytics/blob/master/src/jquery.universal-analytics.js

```
$(document).on('mousedown', 'a', function () {
  if ((this.protocol === 'http:' || this.protocol === 'https:') && this.hostname.indexOf(document.location.hostname) === -1) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound', this.hostname, this.pathname);
  }
});
```

Comment: This appears to do the trick nicely & should be the accepted answer, assuming it is acceptable to have jQuery as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation. The `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent'])` is no longer valid. You must use the new function;
`ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav buttons', 4);`

[Event Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Answer (score 0):

Universal Analytics Event tracking has changed.

This is the [new event tracking code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events):

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'opt_label', opt_value); // value is a number
```

So to rewrite your code it would look like this:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {

      ga('send', 'event','Outbound', 'Click', this.href);
      setTimeout('document.location = "' + this.href + '"', 100);
      return false;
}
```

Then you can attach it to the link with `onclick=` or create a javascript event listener. I usually do the event listener because I try and stay away form mixing html and JS in line.

Comment: Yeah, I just copied the function you listed and it seemed to be a little weird. I rewrote it in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nicomiceli/CRSBc/ just uncomment the ga code and comment out the console.log - i added that for a debugger. (just make sure the you have jquery on the site.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `.on('MouseDown')` because it won't track accurately. It still misses click events on slower connections and reports fake clicks if a user mouses down and then drags away.

NikZilla [provides an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21435287/3018023) using `.on('click')` with jquery and [Universal Analytics hitCallback function](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback). I've combined it with the ability to track all outbound links [as referenced in another answer](https://github.com/tomfuertes/jquery-universal-analytics/blob/master/src/jquery.universal-analytics.js).

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  if ((this.protocol === 'http:' || this.protocol === 'https:') && this.hostname.indexOf(document.location.hostname) === -1) {
    var obj = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    ga('send', 'event', 'Outbound', this.hostname, this.pathname, 0, {
                        'hitCallback': function() {
                            obj.off(e);
                            obj[0].click();
                            }
                    });
  }

});

</script>
```